# Terraform Provider Retrieval Error: Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider -/artifactory

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a providers.tf script as below:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
    
    artifactory = {
      source = "registry.terraform.io/jfrog/artifactory"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
  alias  = "west"
}
```

Once the script is executed on the backend, the following error message appears:

```
    Error: Failed to query available provider packages
    Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider -/artifactory:
    provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
    registry.terraform.io/-/artifactory
```

I've tried a number of ways including setting the exact version of aws, updating the source address, slacking the version requirement of artifactory. But none of them works.
Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `terraform init -upgrade`?

Comment: Yes, but it still fails.

Comment: What's the system setup you are using? For example, I've seen similar issues on WSL2 with Windows, where it has DNS lookup issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the provider block properly. It should be:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    artifactory = {
      source = "jfrog/artifactory"
      version = "7.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems the documentation is a bit outdated, but this should work:

```
- Installing jfrog/artifactory v7.0.0...
- Installed jfrog/artifactory v7.0.0 (signed by a HashiCorp partner, key ID 6B219DCCD7639232)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same error message after adopting this change.

Comment: That's impossible. Can you remove the `.terraform` folder and run `terraform init`?

Comment: @MarkoE were you able to make it work for you?

Comment: Well, I was able to download the provider. I have no artifactory to test against.

Comment: Thanks. I came across similar use case today but not with Artifactory but with cad/schemaregistry and i am able to downland it without issues.